# My node.js hbase code don't retrieve data

Tags: node.js, null, hbase

I work with hbase and node.js. I write my code:

```
var hbase = require('hbase');
http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
hbase()
  .getRow('DatosBicing', '1*')
  .get('datos:bikes',  function(error, value){
          console.log('get');
          console.log(value);
          console.log('get 1');
          response.end();

  }); 

   }).listen(8000,'localhost');
```

Thiw code don't retrieve the row. It retrieves null. The trace messages are:

```
[cloudera@localhost ejemplos]$ node  pruebahbase11.js
get
null
get 1
```

The hbase table data are:

```
hbase(main):003:0> scan 'DatosBicing', {LIMIT => 1, FILTER => "PrefixFilter ('1')"}
ROW                                         COLUMN+CELL                                                                                                                 
1                                          column=datos:bikes, timestamp=2752014145010832, value=22                                                                    
1                                          column=datos:height, timestamp=2752014145010832, value=21                                                                  
1                                          column=datos:lat, timestamp=2752014145010832,       value=41.3979520                                                              
1                                          column=datos:long, timestamp=2752014145010832, value=2.18004200                                                             
1                                          column=datos:nearby, timestamp=2752014145010832, value=24*369*387*426                                                       
1                                          column=datos:slots, timestamp=2752014145010832, value=2                                                                     
1                                          column=datos:status, timestamp=2752014145010832, value=OPN                                                                  
1                                          column=datos:street, timestamp=2752014145010832, value=Gran Via Corts Catalanes                                             
1                                          column=datos:streetNumber, timestamp=2752014145010832, value=760
```

1 row(s) in 0.0670 seconds

Why does this code retrieve null?. Does it depend on the configuration of hbae?